# Why my navigation controller has like a margin

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSyxU.png)
Im creating this view programmatically and is taking a lot of space between the navigation bar and safe area I suppose, is there any way to place this without any margin?

I have tried to hide the nav, but I need to show the title of the view

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask] for information about what needs to be included in a question to make it debuggable and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before. Im betting you have your tabBarController in a UINavigationController and also your viewControllers in a  NavigationController, giving you the extra top padding. In a nutShell remove one of the navigationController.

Comment: Specifically, don't put the tab bar in a nav controller.

Comment: Thank you bro, that was exactly the problem, I was getting confuse about that, but yeah. That solved it